# wp_query for more fields plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-query, customization

I use this plugin : http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/more-fields/page/2

How use WP_QUERY for this inputs ?!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What have you done already?

Answer (score 0):

[More fields Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/more-fields/) is to enter additional input into the post, page etc. And that is Custom Fields in WordPress.

To use `WP_Query()` for those Custom Fields input, you have to query for the meta_key.

```
<?php
//Query for only my custom field value
$args = array(
          'meta_key' => 'your_field_key'
        );

$wpse_query = new WP_Query($args);

while( $wpse_query->have_posts() ):
$wpse_query->the_post();

   if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_field_key', true ) != '' ):
      echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_field_key', true );

endwhile;
?>
```

Learn more from Codex: [`WP_Query()` - Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

More related answers can be found [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=echo+Custom+Fields+data).

Additionally, More Fields plugin is not actively maintained, so it's not fit for updated WordPress. Better use other plugins like: **Advanced Custom Fields**, or the like.

Comment: Thx, How use check variable is exists ? 
after this code : 'meta_key' => 'your_field_key'
check your_field_key == 'ok' ?

Comment: Updated the answer with an `if()` before the `echo`. If the answer satisfy your need, don't forget to upvote it and mark the answer as accepted. We guys work here for reputation. :)